# How to write a bash script to give another program response

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that does several tasks, including `python manage.py syncdb` on a fresh database. This command asks for input, like the login info for the admin. Currently, I just type this into the command line every time. Is there a way I can automatically provide these replies as part of the bash script?

Thanks, I don't really know anything about bash.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/38825/bash-like-command-substitution-in-ssh-or-how-to-request-things-from-ssh-client) on SF, but this one is more general, and it's good to have on SO.

"You want to use [expect](http://expect.nist.gov/) for this. It's probably already on your machine [try `which expect`]. It's the standard tool for any kind of interactive command-line automation. It's a Tcl library, so you'll get some Tcl skills along the way for free. Beware; it's addictive."

I should mention in this case that there is also [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect), which is a Python expect-alike.

```
#!/path/to/expect
spawn python manage.py syncdb
expect "login:*"
send -- "myuser\r"
expect "*ssword:*"
send -- "mypass\r"
interact
```

Answer (score 3):

If the program in question cannot read the input from `stdin` such as:

```
echo "some input" | your_progam
```

then you'll need to look to something like `expect` and/or `autoexepect`

Answer (score 0):

You can give defaults values to the variables. In line 4 and 5, if the variables RSRC and LOCAL aren't set, they are set to those default values. This way you can give the options to your script or use the default ones

```
#!/bin/bash
RSRC=$1
LOCAL=$2
: ${RSRC:="/var/www"}
: ${LOCAL:="/disk2/backup/remote/hot"}
rsync -avz -e 'ssh ' user@myserver:$RSRC $LOCAL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, given an example `login.py` script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    user = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    passwd = sys.stdin.readline().strip()

    if user == 'root' and passwd == 'password':
        print 'Login successful'
        sys.exit(0)

    sys.stderr.write('error: invalid username or password\n')
    sys.exit(1)
```

good-credentials.txt

```
root
password
```

bad-credentials.txt

```
user
foo
```

Then you can do the login automatically using:

```
$cat good-credentials.txt | python login.py
Login successful

$cat bad-credentials.txt | python login.py 
error: invalid username or password
```

The down-side of this approach is you're storing your password in plain text, which isn't great practice.